# How to merge two list based on a function in python?

Tags: python

I have two equal size lists and i want to make a third one that will contain the differences of each previous two:

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[2,1,3,2]
```

and i want to compute `c=[a[0]-b[0],a[1]-b[1],a[2]-b[2],a[3]-b[3],]`
Is there a pythonic way for that?

Answer (score 7):

List comprehension.

```
[x - y for (x, y) in zip(a, b)]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
from operator import sub

a=[1,2,3,4]
b=[2,1,3,2]

print map(sub, a, b)
# [-1, 1, 0, 2]
```

Answer (score 4):

> How to merge two list based on a function in python?

You're looking for `zip` and a list comprehension:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4]
>>> b=[2,1,3,2]
>>> def func(x,y):
...     return x-y
>>> c = [func(x,y) for x,y in zip(a,b)]
>>> c
[-1, 1, 0, 2]
```

help on `zip`:

```
zip(seq1 [, seq2 [...]]) -> [(seq1[0], seq2[0] ...), (...)]
```

```
Return a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the i-th element
from each of the argument sequences.  The returned list is truncated
in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.
```

Use [`itertools.izip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) for memory efficient solution as it returns an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` with list comprehension:

```
>> [x-y for (x, y) in zip(a, b)]
```